# Module is not getting started with #url

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, single-page-application, backbone-routing

I am working on an application in which we have used backbone and marionette js. Nw the problem is with routing. While navigation through the application flow if works fine. In one of the module if you refresh the page then the backbne module is not getting started. Means if you try to access that module with url **#URL** then it will not start.

Here is the code for that module

```
define(["app"], function (Splanner) {
    Splanner.module("RegistrationModule", function (Registration, Splanner, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        Registration.startWithParent = false;

        Registration.onStart = function () {
            console.log('Module Start');
        };
        Registration.onStop = function () {
            console.log('Module Stop');
        };
    });

    Splanner.module("RegistrationRouter", function (RegistrationRouter, Splanner, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

        RegistrationRouter.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
            appRoutes: {
                "newvisitor/registration": "visitorRegistration"
            }
        });

        var executeAction = function (controllerAPI, arg) {
            Splanner.startModule("RegistrationModule");
            controllerAPI(arg);
        };

        var API = {
            visitorRegistration: function () {
                require(["modules/visitor/registration/RegistrationController"], function (RegistrationController) {
                    executeAction(RegistrationController.showVisitorRegistration);
                });
            }
        };

        Splanner.on("visitor:registration:show", function (myVisitor) {
            Splanner.navigate("newvisitor/registration");
            API.visitorRegistration(myVisitor);
        });
        Splanner.addInitializer(function () {
            new RegistrationRouter.Router({
                controller: API
            });
        });

    });
    return Splanner.RegistrationRouter;
});
```

Now when I go through application flow it is not working, but the when I use **#newvisitor/registration** url the module is not getting started.

Answer (score 0):

This setup looks like the one i use, following the marionette book I read. In mine any module i want available at start i have placed a call for it in my app.js file triggering after initialization. Not sure if this will be the same for you but I got caught out when starting this and not having the modules avaliable

```
MyApp.on("initialize:after", function() {
      if (Backbone.history) {
         require([
            "apps/dashboard/dashboard_app",
            "apps/server/server_app",
            "apps/installations/installations_app",
            "apps/system_check/system_check_app",
            "apps/accounts/account_management_app",

         ], function() {
            Backbone.history.start();

            if (MyApp.getCurrentRoute() === "") {
               MyApp.trigger("dashboard:show");
            }
         });
      }
   });
```